# Google Spreadsheet Script - a more direct way of dumping array to sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Just wondering if anyone could give me some pointers on a more direct way of replacing / overwrite a column on the SpreadSheet with that from a 2D array (memory).

Currently, the below code writes value to cell by scrolling down row-by-row via a "for" loop. This was fine but now that the sheet's grown over 7k rows, this script has approach execution time limit.

The process of saving the entire sheet to memory array and calculations took very little time, it's the for loop that calls the sheet cell-by-cell that seems to take forever.

There must be a more direct way of a replacing an entire column rather than scrolling cell by cell down the column to update values.

Any pointers would be much appreciated, please forgive my ignorance, I'm only very new to scripting.

Regards
M

```
   function UnitPrice() {
      var range = Stocklist.getRange(1, 1, LastRow, LastColumn).getValues();  

      for (var i=1; i < (LastRow); i++){
        var PurposeArray = range[i][PurposeCol-1]; 
        var ListedArray = range[i][ListedCol-1];
        var QtyArray = range[i][QtyCol-1];
        var CostArray = range[i][Cost$Col-1];
        var Unit$Array = range[i][Unit$Col-1]; 
        var PremiumArray = range[i][PremiumCol-1];

        if (QtyArray!="0" && QtyArray!=""){
          range[i][Unit$Col-1] = CostArray*(1+PremiumArray)/QtyArray;
        } else{
          range[i][Unit$Col-1] = "";
        } 

        if (ListedArray!=""&&PurposeArray=="" ){           
            range[i][PurposeCol-1] = "Stock";
        }
      }


      //update spreadsheet's column "Unit$Col" with values from column 25 of 'range' array.
      for (var j=1; j < LastRow; j++){
        Stocklist.getRange(j+1, Unit$Col).setValue(range[j][Unit$Col-1]);
        Stocklist.getRange(j+1, PurposeCol).setValue(range[j][PurposeCol-1]); 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use range.setvalues() see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)

Doing loads of reads and writes is very slow, group them as a single read and a single write when possible.

Comment: That awesome! exactly what I needed, thanks you so much. I understand how the function work at a high level but now having trouble applying the function to existing code to make it work. Again my apologies for the lack of coding experience.

Comment: This is what I want to do in a nut shell, replacing a column of the spreadsheet with a column from the array, but having all sorts of syntax/code error...Stocklist.getRange(Unit$Col).setValues(range[Unit$Col-1]);

Comment: Sounds like you should do a java script tutorial on arrays. ... you need a 2 dimensional array. Something like:  Stocklist.getRange(Unit$Col).setValues(range)